# Problems with std::stoi in C++ using ubuntu

Tags: c++, string

I am receiving a compile error when I try to compile the simple program below.

`error: ‘stoi’ was not declared in this scope`

I've tried to include both `#include <string>` and `#include <string.h>` and I still am having those issues. I am using Ubuntu and I cannot remember how I installed g++ but I am sure it was using the apt-get install g++ command, so I do not know what version of g++ or the C++ libraries I am using.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct Data
{
    string fname;
    string lname;
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    bool toContinue = true;
    Data data;
    string buffer;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            getline(cin,data.fname);
            getline(cin,data.lname);
            getline(cin,buffer);
            data.age = stoi(buffer);
            cout<<data.fname<<" ";
            cout<<data.lname<<" ";
            cout<<data.age<<endl;
        }
        catch(std::invalid_argument)
        {
            cerr<<"Unable to parse integer";
        }
    }while(toContinue);

    return 0;
}
```

My goal is to be able to use exception handling in case the user enters junk for any of the variables.

Comment: It's C++11-only, so compile with `-std=c++11`. Also, `string.h` is the C string header, nothing to do with `std::string`.

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look at the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), you'll see that it was introduced in C++11. You'll have to compile your code with the `-std=c++11` option to enable those features because code isn't compiled as C++11 by default.

Drew commented saying that if you are using C++03, you can use

[`boost::lexical_cast<int>(buffer)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)

Comment: And conversely if C++03 is being used, [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) would be worth investigating.

Comment: @DrewDormann I appreciate the addition, I hope you don't mind me integrating it into my answer.

Comment: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11’ I am getting that... how do I compile command line to make that work?

Comment: all:
 g++ main.cpp -c -std=c++11
 g++ main.o -o program
 rm *.o
 ./program

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Comment: Sorry, looks like I got it, I had it in my -c part of my g++ instead of my -o part (in my make file) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out I needed this in order for it to work...

```
g++ -std=c++0x ./main.cpp
```